# C rand() slightly biased

Tags: c, random, montecarlo

I'm using the rand() function from the Standard c Library to generate numbers for a Monte Carlo simulation in the range 0 to 1 using:

```
(double)rand()/RAND_MAX
```

But I noticed that the result was slightly off. I checked at which value the generated numbers averaged out and it was slightly under the expected 0.5.

I read that rand() is Modulo biased but I’m not using modulo here. Is there a more precise way to generate numbers between 1 and 0?

Edit:
I'm fairly new to Prngs so i didn't know that some prngs arent threadsafe. I should have mentioned that i used rand() multithreaded.
Regardless, your answers helped me to find a faster and threadsafe rng.

Comment: Hitting *exactly* 0.5 isn't very likely even in an ideal case, how much was it off by for how many numbers?

Comment: At a billion+ iterations or so it averaged out at about 0.495, whichever significantly biased my result. After some more research if found this in a CERN paper for prngs: https://luscher.web.cern.ch/luscher/ranlux/

Comment: Modern PRNG:s tend to be pretty easy and quick to implement. xoroshiro was very good a few years ago, and perhaps it still is, but there are likely faster and better (as in not failing TestU01 and PractRand as much) PRNG:s out there now. Algorithms from the 90s will probably not cut it.

Comment: Which standard C library did you use? How did you compute the average? Show your code.

Comment: If you care enough about the randomness to measure its quality, don't use `rand()`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not just for you. It is good for you that you found some solution for yourself. But there is still an issue that whatever `rand` you were using seems to be biased. That is information that ought to be clarified for future readers. Tell us which standard C library you use C. The GNU C library? Some other library? How did you compute the average? Edit the question to state the library used and to include the code.

Comment: The rand() I was using was from the c99 stdlib. I computed it by just adding N random doubles and than dividing by N. It was only biased when using it multithreaded. In single a single thread it wasnt.

Comment: @Hellstormer: There is no “c99 stdlib.” The C standard specifies an interface: Ways to call various routines and some specifications of what they should return. It does not fully define an implementation. The GNU C library is one implementation. Microsoft has another. Tell us which library you used, including which version. Also show the code you used to compute the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favourite is [xoroshiro](https://prng.di.unimi.it/). It passes most pseudorandomness tests and it's incredibly fast, much faster than `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your C implementation.   Some have a higher quality implementation of `rand` than others.   Maybe use `arc4random`, or some other crypto based PRNG instead.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, in the typical case `rand()` is a notoriously poor PRNG.  (On my system, `man rand` prints "rand, rand_r, srand, sranddev -- bad random number generator".)

`rand` tends to be fine for some things, but I think it's pretty widely agreed that it's never good enough for decent Monte Carol simulation.  Quite aside from its distribution, its period tends not to be long enough.  (Typical implementations keep ~32 bits of state, so they start repeating after 4.3 billion samples.)

With that said, `(double)rand()/RAND_MAX` is averaging out at 0.5 for me on my machine -- to be precise, I got 0.500004 after 1,000,000,000 samples.  I suspect your system's implementation may be broken -- one possibility that pops to mind is that it is wrongly emitting numbers in the range from 0 to `RAND_MAX-1`.  You might try averaging `rand()/(RAND_MAX-1.)` and see what happens.

(ObIdleOpinionating: I wish systems would implement `rand()` better, instead of telling you not to use it and giving you a better PRNG under a different, nonstandard name.  But it doesn't matter what I wish, because implementing a crappy `rand()` alongside a better-but-nonstandard alternatively-named version is what everybody seems to do.)

Comment: `rand` is an API, not a pseudo-random number generator. Without a specific implementation specified, it is not correct to say it is a poor generator. It could be correct to say some historic implementations have been poor.

Comment: I think that the main problem of `rand` is that the C Standard itself doesn't specify any particular quality target other than RAND_MAX beeing at least 32767. It literally says *"There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs"*. POSIX, at leas,t added a requirement about the minimum period.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Theoretically you're right, and I wish I could agree with you.  But the prevalence of poor implementations seems to be at least 95%, and the consensus advice (as reflected in this thread!) is "Don't use it".